# SQL - How to Use DateDiff condition to exclude past records and work only on newly inserted records

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a View which List the records which are less than equal to 80 days old. The View is on an existing table(**AeoiCaptureLog**) which already has records from the past.

I want to implement a filter in the view, so the date condition (<=80) is only active on data inserted after the view is deployed in live environment and it should not consider already existing data which are 80 days old or less. But after 100 days of deployment it should still return last 80 days of data, so i assume we cannot use view creation date as a parameter.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vAeoiSurplusCaseCreation] AS
Select AccessNumber, DocumentID, LastModifiedDate, StatusCode
FROM AeoiCaptureLog 
WHERE StatusCode IN (6, 13, 15) 
AND DATEDIFF(dd, [LastModifiedDate], GETDATE()) <= 80
```

Please feel free and let me know if any queries.

Important thing to note is :

- On Day 1 of deployment - The view should not return any data(if there are no new records inserted in AeoiCaptureLog after the View is deployed)
  BUT
- On Day 100 after deployment - The view should only return last 80 days of data.

Comment: when is day 1???

Comment: What is "day 1 of deployment"? What is "day 100 after deployment"? What is meant by *deployment* in this context? Square brackets are used around identifiers is Transact SQL (Microsoft SQL Server), not MySQL. (I suspect the mysql tag is on this question is a mistake, and was meant to be a tag for Microsoft SQL Server.) In any case, predicates on bare columns are preferred over expressions...  do the comparison the bare LastModifiedDate column, and do a greater than or equal to an expression that returns a date value.  e.g. `LastModifiedDate >=  DATEADD(dd,GETDATE(),-80)`

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server (Transact-SQL), we could do something like this:

```
 AND LastModifiedDate >= DATEADD(dd,GETDATE(),-80)
 AND LastModifiedDate >  CAST('2018-05-17' AS DATETIME)
```

where the literal '2018-05-17' represents "Day 1 of deployment"

The first conditions looks back 80 days.

The second condition looks back to a specified date.

Since both of those have to evaluate to TRUE, we'll limit the return to the greater of the two date values.

We could make this uglier, and use a complicated CASE expression to return the greater of the two date values, and do a single comparison.

---

With MySQL it would be similar approach

```
 AND LastModifiedDate >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -80 DAYS
 AND LastModifiedDate >  '2018-05-17' + INTERVAL 0 DAYS
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest. I'm commenting to stress to the OP that there is no good way to determine "day 1 of deployment", unless it is either stored in another table, or hard coded (as this answer has done).

Comment: Thanks Spencer. this certainly helps. On a different note, do you think it will work as expected, if i just add another AND condition to my existing view like " AND LastModifiedDate > (select create_date from sys.views where name = 'vAeoiSurplusCaseCreation')"

Comment: That would work only if that SELECT in the subquery is guaranteed to return no more than one row. Maybe wrap `create_date` in a MIN() or MAX() function, in case there is more than one row e.g. `> (select MAX(create_date) from ...`. And you might want to handle a condition where there are no rows, and a NULL is returned. e.g. `> (select COALESCE(MAX(create_date),GET_DATE()) from ...`   (and make sure the user executing the query has sufficient privileges to select from `sys.views`.

Comment: Also consider what happens to `create_date` when the view is dropped and recreated. Also consider that two (or more) schemas can contain a view with the same name... you probably want to narrow down the rows returned from sys.views to just the [dbo]  schema.